# What is the most efficient way to READ/WRITE million rows from a remote server?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can someone point me on efficient methods (to avoid OUT OF MEMORY error)  to READ/WRITE millions of rows from a remote server using SQLAlchemy and Python ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your result set when reading the data so you only deal with one row at a time for example instead of pulling the entire data-set into memory before you actually process them.

And for writing, do the same. Just work on one record at a time for efficiency purposes.